# es6 way to create an array of arrays with random numbers?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Trying to create an array of arrays of value 1 or 0. But each array has either [0,0,0,0,0,0] or [1,1,1,1,1,1] since fill isn't a callback. I need it random like [0, 1, 0, 0, 1] What would be an es6 way of creating an array of arrays of values 0 or 1?

```
const createBoard = function({width, height}) {


  const board = Array(height).fill([])
  .map(row => row.concat( Array(width).fill( Math.round(Math.random()) ) ))


 return board
}

createboard({width: 5, height: 10})
```

I can do this with for loops but I want it more declarative.

```
const createBoard = function({width, height}) {
  let board = []
  for(let row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    board.push([])
    for(let cell = 0; cell < width; cell++) {
      board[row].push(Math.round(Math.random()))
    }
  }

  return board
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Using_arrow_functions_and_Array.from) to create the outer and inner arrays. Since Array#from expects an object with the `length` property, you can supply `height` or `width` as the length, and use the callback to generate whatever values you need in to array.

```js
const createBoard = ({width, height}) => 
  Array.from({ length: height }, 
    () => Array.from({ length: width }, 
      () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
    )
  );

const board = createBoard({width: 5, height: 10});

console.log(JSON.stringify(board));
```

Comment: this seems less readable than a nested for loop. Should I just use for loops instead? But it's probably because i'm not used to it so i'll just go with this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing your logic with minor change, this should work

```
x = Array(5).fill([]).map(x => (Math.random(0,1) < 0.5) ? 0 : 1 )
```